# ExtJS: How to add new object to Store and send POST request to RESTful server

Tags: rest, web-services, extjs

I am creating a Todo application with ExtJS 6. My application should fetch data, here are Todos list from a Server using RESTful web service, and add new Todo task and send this new task to store in the Server. For the fetching part, it was successfully to show the data from the server, but I still facing a problem with the adding data and send back to the server.

Here are components that I have:

- A `View` called `ToDoList` which contains 1 `textfield` and 1 `button` to add new **Todo** task:

  ```
  Ext.define('ToDo.view.toDoList.ToDoList',{
  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

  requires: [
      'ToDo.view.toDoList.ToDoListController',
      'ToDo.view.toDoList.ToDoListModel'
  ],
  xtype: 'app-todoList',
  controller: 'todoList',
  viewModel: {
      type: 'todoList'
  },

  items: [{
      xtype: 'container',
      items: [{
          xtype: 'container',
          layout: 'hbox',
          cls: 'task-entry-panel',
          defaults: {
              flex: 1
          },
          items: [{
              reference: 'newToDo',
              xtype: 'textfield',
              emptyText: 'Enter a new todo here'
          },
          {
              xtype: 'button',
              name: 'addNewToDo',
              cls: 'btn-orange',
              text: 'Add',
              maxWidth: 50,
              handler: 'onAddToDo'
          }]
      }]
  }]
  });
  ```
- My `ViewModel` called `ToDoListModel` which contains store object named **todos**, which including 3 parameters: `id, desc and done`.

  ```
  Ext.define('ToDo.view.toDoList.ToDoListModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
  alias: 'viewmodel.todoList',
  stores:{
      todos: {
          fields: [{ 
              name: 'id',
              type: 'string'
          },
          {
              name: 'desc', 
              type: 'string'
          },
          {
              name: 'done', 
              type: 'boolean'
          }],
          autoLoad: true,
          sorters: [{
              property: 'done',
              direction: 'ASC'
          }],
          proxy: {
              type: 'rest',
              url: 'http://localhost:8082/RegistrationForm/tasks/',
              reader: {
                  type: 'json'
              },
              writer: {
                  type: 'json'
              }
          }
      }
  }

  });
  ```

And My `ViewController` called: `ToDoListController` looks like:

```
Ext.define('ToDo.view.toDoList.ToDoListController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.todoList',
views: ['ToDo.view.toDoList.ToDoList'],

init: function(){
    var me = this;
    this.getViewModel().data.todos.load(function(records){
        Ext.each(records, function(record){
            console.log(record);
            me.addToDoToView(record);
        });
    });

    Ext.getBody().on('click', function(event, target){
        me.onDelete(event, target);
    }, null, {
        delegate: '.fa-times'
    });
},
onAddToDo: function () {

    var store = this.getViewModel().data.todos;

    var desc = this.lookupReference('newToDo').value.trim();

    **HOW CAN I ADD NEW OBJECT TO STORE AND PERFORM POST REQUEST HERE TO THE SERVER**


},
addToDoToView: function(record){
    this.view.add([{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        cls: 'row',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            boxLabel: record.get('desc'),
            checked: record.get('done'),
            flex: 1
        },
                {
                    html: '<a class="hidden" href="#"><i taskId="'+ record.get('id') + '" class="fa fa-times"></i></a>'
                }]
    }]);
},

onDelete: function(event, target){
    var store = this.getViewModel.data.todos;
    var targetCmp = Ext.get(target);
    var id = targetCmp.getAttribute('taskId');
    store.remove(store.getById('id'));
    store.sync({
        success: function(){
            this.view.remove(targetCmp.up('.row').id)
        },
        scope: this
    });
}

});
```

And when the user click to the **Add Button**, the function **onAddToDo()** in the **Controller** will be call, here it will get the new task from the **textfield** (here **desc** variable), create a new Todo object and then send this object to the server using POST request. My service in the server will look like:

```
//ADD new Todo
@RequestMapping(value = "/tasks/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody Todo todo,    UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
    //add this new Todo object to the database 
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

What I would like to do is after user entering new Task, I will pack it as new object, structure look like: `{'id'=1, 'desc'='what user entered','done'=false}` and send it as the RequestBody of the POST method to the server. Can anyone guide me how can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add the record to the store by using `add()` function.

```
store.add({id:1, desc:'what user entered',done:false});
```

Then you can call `sync()` function which will call the create api of the store and send the inserted data to server.

```
store.sync();
```

`sync()` synchronizes the store with server in 3 cases that are new record creation, record updation and record deletion. So here when we add a new record and call `sync()`, it will send only the newly added record to the server as it is not present at server to the URL specified in store

Comment: hi  ankit, thank for your hint, but can you please explain me a bit more about store.sync() function? How should I use it? Thank you

Comment: hi ankit, I already add new data to store and then using store.sync() but it still not work. I think my proxy configuration is somewhere wrong. Can you please check in the code above if I have a right configuration for the store's proxy. Thank you

Comment: It should work. Could you create a working fiddle,to understand your issue